# Travelling salesman but doesn’t have to be most efficient route just trace the roads. (Python and QGIS)

Tags: qgis, python, coordinates, routing, travelling-salesman

I’ve got a project; for one part of this project I intend to draw a route over a shapefile, it contains 9000 nodes.

**What I’ve tried:**

- Generating routes on a map layer in QGIS by following the lines of the shapefile layer and pointing and clicking with Valhalla (limited to certain amount of stops), and various other similar plugins such as osrm, etc
- Chinese postman plug-in for QGIS (crashed), not ideal since it’s attempting to find shortest route when I just need a route, any route.
- Garmin Basecamp (which nearly worked but the route only snapped to the road if you clicked near enough to the last waypoint)
- Hosting an opentripplanner routing server to increase the amount of stops I can use in QGIS plugins (by calling localhost) but there’s a bug where without GTFS data it won’t generate routes so I’m waiting for that to be fixed.

**What I’m currently doing:**

Using a Python algorithm to convert a shapefile to a graph so I can then try to use said graph to route perhaps using Python too, it’s by this person: https://GitHub.com/Caesar0301/s2g

That algorithm is taking some time to convert so before I find out whether it doesn’t work I wanted to find out if I’m over complicating things and there’s a simpler solution.

So, how can I use python to trace over a shapefile automatically without having to wait to calculate efficiency and such, but covers the area? Whereupon then I can export the coordinates of the traced route?

**Update**

So the algorithm converting my shapefile took seven days to inspect but it's finshed. However while it did it's job and there were no errors, it didn't save anywhere, so I can't use the graph. My fault though, I should have added a part in the code to save it or print it or whatever.

Now for some good news, I found this:

https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Processing-tools

Apparently there are scripts for doing these kinds of things that people have made, i've tried the lines to route one but couldn't get it to work as it's for an older version of qgis (which I only realised after not getting it to work) but i'm going to see if I can find an updated one while I play the seven day algorithm again or figure out how to tweak the one I tried to work in my version of qgis 3.23

**Update 2**

Found a plugin called NNjoin which I think reorders your points in a layer to be ordered according to nearest neighbour which if I understand it correctly means Points to path should be more accurate for me as my shapefile order is all wacko.

[image: Example]

Comment: Great question, interesting to see the outcome of this.

How large an area does the route cover out of interest?

Comment: @ScoGer A road map of North America but it’s major roads and highways, so it’s nowhere as detailed as google maps. If successful I plan to try other countries.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You have lots of points and then what? :D Do you want to connect them all in a long line? In the shortest line?

Comment: @bugmenot123 Basically I intend to create a route along the roads (doesn’t have to be shortest just cover the roads), then export the coords which as a route instead of a shapefile should be one line, I plan to input those coords into scratch code I made which turns the coordinates into lines and then exports them to json.xml to be used in a Garmin Connect IQ app where I then display the lines as a map. The route part is simply so I can export the coordinates as a single line matching the road as exporting the points directly from the shp caused them to link in my Garmin app in a weird way.

Comment: So you also have road lines as a layer? Or are your "nodes" actually representing roads?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have one layer, a line shapefile that represents roads (multiple lines), I need to make a route from that layer as a new layer (one continous line) so that I can export the coordinates be in the right order for my scratch code.

I need a way to make that route without wasting time and memory of my pc calculating the efficiency and shortest route, I just need to cover the roads, thats it.

Comment: One single route that consists of all the roads in your layer concatenated in a continuous line? I still don't think the task is clear. Could you maybe add a drawing or concrete example to the post?

Comment: You are correct, but I shall add a drawing too.